# My Toast alert does not appear during android emulation

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin android development, I don't understand why my "toast" is not showing or working properly during emulation.

Here is the main activity of my application:

```
package paris.ksainthi.soundpark

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import android.widget.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val submit: Button   = findViewById(R.id.loginSubmit)
        val email:  EditText = findViewById(R.id.loginMailEditText)
        val emailText: Editable = email.getText()
        submit.setOnClickListener {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "L'adresse e-mail est %s".format(emailText.toString()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        }
    }
}
```

You will find attached part of my code concerning the layout

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/loginMailInputLayout"
            style="@style/Widget.Soundpark.TextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/login_mail_field"
            android:textColorHint="@color/purple_200"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/purple_200">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/loginMailEditText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/purple_200"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/loginSubmit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/login_submit" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `.show()`

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "L'adresse e-mail est %s".format(emailText.toString()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```